# Move all files of certain filetype in all sub directories up one level

Tags: command-line, filenames, mv

I have a directory with lots of sub-directories. The sub-directories each have unique names.

I would like to take every file ending with '.nc' in the sub-directories and move those files up one level.

Is there a way to do this in the terminal?

Comment: Can we assume that the filenames are distinct from their containing directory, so that there's no collision? e.g. a file named `subdir1.nc` does not exist in a directory named `subdir1.nc`?  And with these files in various subdirectories, do you want them moved one level up from where they are, or up one level from where *you* are, at the top somewhere?

Comment: I would write a recursive directory walker where if I run into a .nc match I move it to .., and if I find a directory, I just call the function with the new directory and it does the same thing all over again until it removes everything off the stack.

Comment: The filenames and the directories all have distinct, unique names.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `find`:

Move each `*.nc` file up one level from where they are:

```
find . -type f -name '*.nc' -execdir mv -i {} .. \;
```

Move each `*.nc` file up one level from where you are (to the parent directory of your current dir):

```
find . -type f -name '*.nc' -exec mv -i {} .. \;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Freddy, simply elegant.  Definitely going to use this in the future.  Faster, than writing a small bash script for sure.

Comment: If you add the -n to the move it won't move files with same name in the directory you are moving to.

Comment: @Freddy question what is the \; for?

Comment: @NiteRain The syntax for actions on single files is `-exec command ;`, the `;` is escaped with a ```\``` to prevent interpretation by the shell and could also be quoted. See `man find`.